# Globally identified elements, Typescript, and Safari-only bug?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, safari, typescript

Suppose you have a select element like this:

```
<select id="Stooge" name="Stooge">
    <option value="0">Moe</option>
    <option value="1">Larry</option>
    <option value="2">Curly</option>
</select>
```

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object), when the browser parses this page, it creates a globally scoped javascript variable `window.Stooge`. So far so good.

In my TypeScript code, I want to refer to the options in a strongly typed way, so I have the following:

```
enum Stooge
{
  Moe,
  Larry,
  Curly
}
```

This is compiled to javascript like so:

```
var Stooge;
(function (Stooge) {
    Stooge[Stooge["Moe"] = 0] = "Moe";
    Stooge[Stooge["Larry"] = 1] = "Larry";
    Stooge[Stooge["Curly"] = 2] = "Curly";
 })(Stooge || (Stooge = {}));  <---error here
```

My problem is: in every browser **except** Safari, this works fine. But in Safari, I get the following error:

```
YourFile.js:[Line X]TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17: The type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object.
```

This only happens with an enum that happens to have the same name as a DOM element, and I imagine this is because there's a conflict between the two definitions, except that this same code does NOT cause any error other than in Safari.

So, why does it work in other browsers and is there a way to work around this in Safari? (I could rename the enum or the DOM element, but I'd like to avoid the need for artificial naming conventions if possible.)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to rename one or the other. There's only one global namespace.

Comment: But then why would it work in FireFox, IE, and Chrome?

Comment: It looks like Safari really insists on keeping that global binding of the name to the DOM node. (I don't have access to Safari to try it, but it should be pretty simple to experiment on jsfiddle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever possible, you should avoid putting anything in the global scope. External modules (soon to be renamed to the simpler name, modules) are a good way to do this. Using external modules, your `enum` would be safely hidden away within the scope of the module and shouldn't conflict with anything else.

Another solution would be to use a constant enum, which is transpiled into plain numbers (i.e. the enum type is erased). So for example, the following TypeScript:

```
const enum Stooge
{
  Moe,
  Larry,
  Curly
}

var x = Stooge.Curly;
```

Results in the following JavaScript:

```
var x = 2 /* Curly */;
```

Your final option is to avoid names that may conflict. When putting something in the global scope, it helps to be as specific as you can to minimize the risk of collision.

Comment: This made me realize that my error was a symptom of the larger problem of not having namespaces and thus dumping everything right on the window object. Adding some namespacing fixed this and is already making my code much cleaner. Now if I only understood the proper use of namespace vs. module.